# How do I get the manufacturer's name for a Windows Multimedia MIDI device?

Tags: c, winapi, winmm

With macOS's Core MIDI, one can request the manufacturer display name of a MIDI device, which will return a descriptive manufacturer name even for devices from uncommon brands.

Is there some equivalent with Win32 / Windows Multimedia?

`MIDIINCAPS` contains a `wMid` field, but this is an integer indicating one out of a hardcoded [list of manufacturers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/multimedia/manufacturer-identifiers) that appears to be both rather limited and possibly rather old, with many of the companies in the list being defunct.

Is there a way to obtain manufacturer strings for these devices, i.e. the manufacturer strings presented by USB in the case of USB MIDI devices?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you could only get the information about the capabilities of the given device by  [MIDIOUTCAPS structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/ns-mmeapi-midioutcaps) and [MIDIINCAPS structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/ns-mmeapi-midiincaps).

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT that’s unfortunate, I suppose there’s no way to figure out what underlying device (USB connection etc) is providing the MIDI input in order to retrieve more data there either